# Kentor AuthServices - serviceCertificates for SP (.pfx with password protected) throwing network password error

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5.2, kentor-authservices

**Error**:
The specified network password is not correct.

Description: An un handled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: The specified network password is not correct.

Reason:
I can only export certificate '.pfx' with the password protected. "Kentor AuthServices" doesn't support password protected as I understand..

It is said that this issue is closed as per below link
https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/457

.Net error: it is because of 'X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet' flag set..

All I did was saved the .pfx file in my solution and pointed the server certificate file path to it. Do I need to do anything else to pass through the error?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When you export the .pfx file in the certificate manager you are prompted for a password, but you can leave it blank and press ok to generate a pfx without passwords.

Having a pfx is a simple approach in test/dev environments where including the pfx in the source lets everyone just get the source and run. That's why I'm doing that for the sample applications in the repository.

But in a production environment the certificates should always be stored securely in the certificate store of the operating system. Never use a pfx file in production. The certificate configuration allows you to specify a certificate store instead of a file name. See [the configuration documentation](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/doc/Configuration.md#signingcertificate-element)

Comment: I am unable to export certificate with private key without password on windows 2008 server. 
I am using store and now getting following error 
Error: Invalid provider type specified. is it my certificate issue? trying on my local machine to prove that it works from my store.

Configuration:
` <kentor.authServices>
...........
 <serviceCertificates>
      <add storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                          findValue="3454B564B758DC59A5D0DDCD087805C06BC85C27" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" use="Signing" />
    </serviceCertificates>
  </kentor.authServices>`

Comment: I was able to make it work when I used SHA1 certificate but with Sha2 certificate I am getting above error. Any thoughts?

Comment: On Windows 10, you can no longer leave the password field blank. Is there any way to generate a certificate without specifying a password or to tell AuthServices what the password is?